# Restoring previously uploaded files in FilePond when editing an article

Tags: filepond

Good day, I have encountered a problem. I am using a FilePond as an image uploader when creating an article on my website. When I create the article, everything works fine. However, when I need to edit the article, I have trouble restoring the previous view of the file pod with the already uploaded images. Is there a solution to this problem? What I mean is that when I click to edit the article, I need to see the file pod with the previously uploaded images, and be able to delete, replace, or upload more images if necessary.

My project is written in PHP using Laravel.

I have tried different options, but I don't understand if it is even possible to implement. Please help me.

Comment: Which options have you already tried?